# Courgette - issue with running test

Tags: testing, protractor, automated-tests, cucumber, courgette

I'm trying to use Courgette to test an Angular web app. This is my first time so I started with a tutorial from [here](https://medium.com/@cg_71438/create-functioning-cucumber-scenarios-in-seconds-dc064dfa52cb):

The thing is that I can't run even the built in test. this is my conf.js:

```
    const path = require('path');
require('babel-core/register');

const specsPath = 'uiTests';
const outputPath = 'uiTestResult';
const cukeTractorPath = 'node_modules/cucumber-protractor/uiTestHelpers';

exports.pomConfig = {
  outputPath,
  timeoutInSeconds: 10,
  pagesPath: path.resolve(specsPath, 'pages'),
  componentsPath: path.resolve(specsPath, 'components'),
  baseUrl: 'https://www.google.com/', // <------------ SET THE URL TO YOUR PROJECT HERE
};

exports.cucumberHtmlReporterConfig = {};

const cukeTags = process.env.cukeTags ? process.env.cukeTags.replace(',', ' or ') : '';

const protractorConfig = {
  directConnect: true,
  ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true,
  framework: 'custom',
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
  specs: [
    `${specsPath}/features/**/*.feature`,
  ],
  capabilities: {
    // acceptInsecureCerts: true, // uncomment to ignore SSL warnings
    'shardTestFiles': !cukeTags && !process.env.linearise && !process.env.showStepDefinitionUsage,
    'maxInstances': 4,
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ['--window-size=1100,800'].concat(process.env.disableHeadless ? [] : ['--headless', '--disable-gpu']),
    },
    // 'browserName': 'firefox',
    // 'moz:firefoxOptions': {
    //   args: [].concat(process.env.disableHeadless ? [] : ['-headless']),
    //   prefs: {
    //     'general.useragent.override': 'Automated tests',
    //   },
    // },
  },
  cucumberOpts: {
    'require': [
      // `${specsPath}/helpers/globals.js`,
      `${cukeTractorPath}/globals.js`,
      `${cukeTractorPath}/hooks/attachScenarioNameBefore.js`,
      `${cukeTractorPath}/hooks/attachScreenshotAfter.js`,
      `${cukeTractorPath}/hooks/pageObjectModelBefore.js`,
      `${cukeTractorPath}/hooks/addMethodsBefore.js`,
      `${cukeTractorPath}/hooks/setDefaultTimeout.js`,
      `${cukeTractorPath}/stepDefinitions/*.js`,
      `${specsPath}/stepDefinitions/*.js`,
      // `${specsPath}/helpers/hooks.js`,
    ],
    'tags': ['~ignore'].concat(cukeTags || []),
    'format': [
      'node_modules/cucumber-protractor/cucumberFormatter.js',
      `json:./${outputPath}/report.json`,
    ].concat(process.env.showStepDefinitionUsage ? 'node_modules/cucumber/lib/formatter/usage_formatter.js' : []),
    'profile': false,
    'no-source': true,
  },
  onPrepare: () => { browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; },
};

exports.config = protractorConfig;
```

And this is the message from the terminal:

```
> c10@1.0.0 ct C:\Users\Melinda\Desktop\Protractor\c10
> set NODE_OPTIONS=--no-deprecation | cuketractor

Brm brm... off we go!
[09:04:34] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver

[09:04:34] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...


DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12249/devtools/browser/748be31e-7dd6-4f56-95d5-eba8122e4012
Test feature::: Clicking I’m Feeling Lucky without typing a search query goes straight to doodles

Getting full url:  https://www.google.com/

Given I am on the 'Google Home' page ---> PASSED

[09:04:38] W/element - more than one element found for locator By(css selector, [name="btnI"]) - the first result will be used

When I click 'I’m Feeling Lucky' ---> FAILED

Then I expect the url to contain 'google.com/doodles' ---> SKIPPED

Screenshot of: Clicking I’m Feeling Lucky without typing a search query goes straight to doodles


*************************************
ScreenshotFilePath:
uiTestResult\Clicking-I’m-Feeling-Lucky-without-typing-a-search-query-goes-straight-to-doodles-1558944278600.png

*************************************
-------------------------------------



---FAIL---
[09:04:38] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running

[09:04:38] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[09:04:38] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)

[09:04:38] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1

Cucumber HTML report C:\Users\Melinda\Desktop\Protractor\c10\uiTestResult\cucumberReport.html generated successfully.

------------------ Scenario Error --------------- Clicking I’m Feeling Lucky without typing a search query goes straight
to doodles
Tags: @google, @google-feeling-lucky
Step: When I click 'I’m Feeling Lucky'
Location: node_modules\cucumber-protractor\uiTestHelpers\stepDefinitions\commonWhenSteps.js:46
Feature: uiTests\features\google.feature:4
Error message: ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
  (Session info: headless chrome=74.0.3729.169)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\Melinda\Desktop\Protractor\c10\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\Melinda\Desktop\Protractor\c10\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (C:\Users\Melinda\Desktop\Protractor\c10\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
From: Task: WebElement.click()
    at Driver.schedule (C:\Users\Melinda\Desktop\Protractor\c10\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:807:17)
    at WebElement.schedule_ (C:\Users\Melinda\Desktop\Protractor\c10\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:2010:25)
    at WebElement.click (C:\Users\Melinda\Desktop\Protractor\c10\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:2092:17)
    at actionFn (C:\Users\Melinda\Desktop\Protractor\c10\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:89:44)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at actionResults.getWebElements.then (C:\Users\Melinda\Desktop\Protractor\c10\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:461:65)
    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\Melinda\Desktop\Protractor\c10\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1376:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\Melinda\Desktop\Protractor\c10\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\Melinda\Desktop\Protractor\c10\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
    at asyncRun (C:\Users\Melinda\Desktop\Protractor\c10\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2927:27)
    at C:\Users\Melinda\Desktop\Protractor\c10\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)Error
    at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\Users\Melinda\Desktop\Protractor\c10\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:459:27)
    at ElementArrayFinder.(anonymous function).args [as click] (C:\Users\Melinda\Desktop\Protractor\c10\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:91:29)
    at ElementFinder.(anonymous function).args [as click] (C:\Users\Melinda\Desktop\Protractor\c10\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:831:22)
-----SCREENSHOT - hold cmd (on mac) and click .png below if using iterm ----
ScreenshotFilePath: uiTestResult\Clicking-I’m-Feeling-Lucky-without-typing-a-search-query-goes-straight-to-doodles-1558944278600.png
---------

┌─────────────────┬────────────┬──────────┐
│ Total Scenarios │ Successful │ Failures │
├─────────────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ 1               │ 0          │ 1        │
└─────────────────┴────────────┴──────────┘
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! c10@1.0.0 ct: `set NODE_OPTIONS=--no-deprecation | cuketractor`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the c10@1.0.0 ct script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Melinda\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-05-27T08_04_38_705Z-debug.log
```

And my log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Melinda\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'ct' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.15.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prect', 'ct', 'postct' ]
5 info lifecycle c10@1.0.0~prect: c10@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle c10@1.0.0~ct: c10@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle c10@1.0.0~ct: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle c10@1.0.0~ct: PATH: C:\Users\Melinda\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Melinda\Desktop\Protractor\c10\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Melinda\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Taurus\bin;C:\Program Files\Taurus\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.2\bin;C:\Users\Melinda\Downloads\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin;C:\Users\Melinda\AppData\Local\Taurus\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\Melinda\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Melinda\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle c10@1.0.0~ct: CWD: C:\Users\Melinda\Desktop\Protractor\c10
10 silly lifecycle c10@1.0.0~ct: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'set NODE_OPTIONS=--no-deprecation | cuketractor' ]
11 silly lifecycle c10@1.0.0~ct: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle c10@1.0.0~ct: Failed to exec ct script
13 verbose stack Error: c10@1.0.0 ct: `set NODE_OPTIONS=--no-deprecation | cuketractor`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Melinda\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Melinda\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid c10@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Melinda\Desktop\Protractor\c10
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Melinda\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "ct"
18 verbose node v10.15.3
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error c10@1.0.0 ct: `set NODE_OPTIONS=--no-deprecation | cuketractor`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the c10@1.0.0 ct script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I'm not even sure where the problem is. According to the error message the element in my 'When' section can't be found but chrome doesn't even open up in the first place.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

It could either be that the sample was broken at the time or that your locale is different to en-gb and the text is wrong in the button. Isn't the most reliable of samples, needs to be changed to something more stable ideally, something hosted by courgette.